# What is best practice for make under maintenance page in reactjs Application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

i want to make a maintenance page in Reactjs Application.
The info of maintenance status will get from API. My idea is put the hook to call api in App.js like this

```
const getMaintenanceState = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await countryApi.getMaintenance();
      console.log('Data: ', data);
    } catch (error) {
      openMessageError(error?.response?.data?.message || ERR_MESSAGE);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getMaintenanceState();
  }, []);
```

and after that, i will show/ hide page maintenance depend on which status i received.

I want to ask us is there the best way to solve this problem. Do you have better way to use wrapper context or redux or something?. Can you share with me?
Thanks

Comment: I think the better way is using Wrapper context and and redux to call api after each time go to other router

Answer (score 0):

if the maintenance status is not required in multiple distant parts of your application, you should use local `useState`. you fetch the data in `useEffect`, store the data in `useState` and then based on this state you display the UI.

As your application grows and if you notice the need to share the maintenance status across multiple distant components, consider transitioning to global state management solutions like Context API or Redux for better scalability and centralized state control.

If the maintenance status changes frequently and needs to be instantly reflected in the application without the need for continuous polling, you may use `websocket`. Maybe you have a live monitoring dashboard or a real-time control panel that needs to display the current maintenance status as it changes.